PowerShell will not start in ConEmu [Windows 10]
I am running Windows 10 22H2, and Powershell used to work fine from ConEmu.  However, when I try to start a PowerShell console or launch powershell.exe from a CMD.exe console in ConEmu, I now get this error:
Version v4.0.30319 of the .NET Framework is not installed and it is required to run version 3 of Windows PowerShell.
PowerShell works fine on its own, when launched from a normal CMD.exe window, or from within Windows Terminal (either on its own or from CMD.exe), but it now always gives this error when attempting to launch it in ConEmu.
I did not change my .NET settings on my own before this happened, but I notice that Windows update has installed several updates to .NET frameworks of various versions, at least one of which (November 21, 2024-KB5048292 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 for Windows 10 Version 22H2) may have caused a problem with another program, although that other issue now appears to be fixed.
I tried to install .NET 4.0.30319, but the installer would not let it install since it is EOL'ed, and I reinstalled .NET 4.8.1, but that did not fix the problem.
I realize that I can use PowerShell on its own or from Windows Terminal, so there is a workaround, but I'd like to fix this if possible.
Any thoughts?

Why are you trying to run PowerShell 3? Do you realize that we're on 7 and that is almost 13 years old?

@Destroy666 - It’s impossible for the author to have PowerShell 3 installed in Windows 10+ since PowerShell 3 and PowerShell 5.1 cannot be installed on the same system and PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 10+. The error suggests there is a .NET environment issue. Installing .NET 3.5 won’t install PowerShell 3, difficult to diagnose with the information provided, since you also can’t reinstall .NET Framework on Windows 10 22H2. PowerShell 7 and PowerShell 5.1 cannot be installed side-by-side

@Destroy666 @Ramhound  I'm not actually trying to run PowerShell 3 specifically.  This is just the error I get when I try to run powershell.exe (which Windows finds in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)

@Ramhound FYI, according to $PSVersionTable, I currently have v5.1.19041.5247 installed (although according to this article it looks like PowerShell v7 and v5.1 can be installed side-by-side)

@DavidManowitz - I am confused. I specifically said it could be installed side-by-side what cannot be installed at the same time as PS 5 is PS 3. My original comment was trying to explain to someone other than you that PS3 cannot be installed on your system

PowerShell 7 and Windows PowerShell 5.1 are different, but similar. PS7 is a cross-platform product, while Windows PS5.1 is the built-in Windows version. They do coexist on computers just fine, which is what Ramhound noted. In your first paragraph you note this error comes when you run PS from CMD, but in your 2nd you note PS runs find from CMD. You won't be able to install Net4: the problem is that somewhere, somehow, on your computer there is an older/invalid PS executable. If ConEmu is the only place that is coming from, you need to look at that and figure out the exe that is running.

Please EDIT your post to resolve the incongruities. Also, we need to know, in precise and clear terms, HOW you are running PS in each of these situations. Finally, you need to look in ConEmu for the full exe path that is being run when you attempt to run PS such that it generates this error.
